# Custom ConfigurationSection: CallbackValidator called with empty string

Tags: c#, configuration

I am writing a custom configuration section, and I would like to validate a configuration property with a callback, like in this example:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

class CustomSection : ConfigurationSection {

    [ConfigurationProperty("stringValue", IsRequired = false)]
    [CallbackValidator(Type = typeof(CustomSection), CallbackMethodName = "ValidateString")]
    public string StringValue {
        get { return (string)this["stringValue"]; }
        set { this["stringValue"] = value; }
    }

    public static void ValidateString(object value) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("string must not be empty.");
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        CustomSection cfg = (CustomSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customSection");
        Console.WriteLine(cfg.StringValue);
    }
}
```

And my App.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="customSection" type="CustomSection, config-section"/>
  </configSections>
  <customSection stringValue="lorem ipsum"/>
</configuration>
```

My problem is that when the `ValidateString` function is called, the `value` parameter is always an empty string, and therefore the validation fails. If i just remove the validator, the string value is correctly initialized to the value in the configuration file.

What am I missing?

**EDIT** I discovered that actually the validation function is being called twice: the first time with the default value of the property, which is an empty string if nothing is specified, the second time with the real value read from the configuration file. Is there a way to modify this behavior?

Comment: Maybe the IsRequired=false in the ConfigurationPropertyAttribute?

Comment: @Ikaso: no, setting IsRequired = true changes nothing.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco : Did the answer you accepted really fix the problem? 

If someone mentions "" (empty string) as a value in the configuration (e.g. stringValue=""), the validator simply returns and `IsRequired = true` does not give any message either. `Isrequired` complains only when the attribute (config property) is totally missing in the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem (except I was creating a custom validator rather than using CallbackValidator) - the validator was being called twice, with the first call passing in default values, and the second call passing in the configured values. Since an empty string was not a valid value for one of my properties, it was causing a configuration error even when I had configured a string value.

So I just changed the validator to return on an empty string, rather than validate it. You can then use the IsRequired attribute to control what happens when a value is not provided.

Comment: Does it really fix the problem? 

If someone mentions "" (empty string) as a value in the configuration (e.g. stringValue=""), the validator simply returns and `IsRequired = true` does not give any message. `Isrequired` complains only when the attribute (config property) is totally missing in the configuration.